# Validating a function over a domain in a computer program.

Tags: calculus, functions

> I am working on the front end of an engineering software, where I have
>   an evaluator to return the value of a function at a point in a given
>   domain, lets call it `eval(f(x))` where `f(x)` is itself single
>   parameter mathematical function, or a combination of such functions,
>   and `x` is any real number.

I need to validate `f(x)` only over a continuous subset of the domain, and if the range of `f(x)` in the given domain is out of bounds, I am supposed to return an error.

I also have a given domain this function is to work over, and the range this function is supposed to spew results over. `eval()` itself returns certain error messages, such as 0 given inside a log function, (My backend can handle this at the domain's end point, so I need my frontend to not return an error when this case hits)

**I basically want to know what individual values of the continuous domain I should evaluate my values at, and how do I evaluate my function in an exclusive range(so I can exclude the endpoints of my domain), what step size should I use to reasonably divide my given domain into values?**

*Keep in mind, I have no other mathematical operators apart from eval() I can use on my function, and I don't want to make my own for the sake of computer power, unless absolutely needed.*

> Extra info about the function: The `f(x)` is a standard or a
>   combination of standard functions, it is never a piece-wise defined
>   function. Also, I only care about the rules I have of my own about the
>   function: (e.g. is log(9999)>2222) rather than if log(0) is valid or
>   not). I can also make do with a check for the range being a continuous
>   range, and not having infinities or any close values in it.
>
> I also don't expect my users to enter functions which are
>   indeterminate, I just want to check the validity of the range of the
>   entered functions(Against my own rules) rather than the correctness of
>   the function itself, in case the function is invalid, I actually want
>   to ignore that since `eval()` already gives errors for those
>   conditions(Apart from `f(x)` domain endpoints, which I need to ignore
>   specifically)

I don't really expect f'(x) to have a very high value either(unless its going towards infinity(e.g.     `-log(x-1) at 1`;

---

Bonus question:

In the future, my `f(x)` also might become `f(x,y)`, with a similar restrictions on the domain of `y`, any advice on that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have given sufficient information. 
(Possibly you have not received sufficient information either.)

Given some knowledge about the bounds of $f'(x),$ you could use a finite number of observations of $f(x)$ to conclude that $f(x)$ was within certain bounds as long as $x$ is within certain bounds, but if $f(x)$ is just some arbitrary function, it could be zero everywhere except when
$1.500001 < x < 1.500002$ and we could have $f(1.5000015) = 10^{100}.$
That's an extreme example, but it does illustrate that you need to know
something more than simply "I have a function" before you can
decide on a suitable step size.

You can estimate $f'(x)$ by evaluating $f(x)$ at slightly different values
of $x,$ but as the previous example illustrated, there's no guarantee that
any particular set of values you used when estimating $f'(x)$
will tell you how large $f'(x)$ can actually get.

In reality, you probably *do* have some kind of information like this about $f(x),$ even if it's very fuzzy information
(such as, "The engineers wouldn't give me a function with such a
large derivative as the one in the example").

**TL;DR:** You can't just treat your function as a black box.
You need *some* kind of specific information about it, even if it's
just that its derivative does not take on any absurdly large values
in your domain.

Comment: Please look at my changes; thank you very much for the help!